# Displaying Objects in a table in a JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have a List of Products that I want to display on my JSP page. The product is basically made up of a picture, a name, and an ID. Originally, I created an html table, and had a row for every product, which was fairly simple to put together using JSTL tags and creating a table row for each Product. I am trying to change the view so that I have 3 products per row, and I can't quite figure out how to achieve that. Inside of my jstl foreach block, do I have to manually keep track of the product index to determine when to create a table row tag? I know there has to be a better way to do this.

Comment: Please show us what you tried. It is easier to answer then.

Comment: I basically had a scripting expression inside of the foreach tag that would update a counter. If the counter reached 2, I would reset it to 0. That way, the counter would only ever have a value of 0,1, or 2. If the counter was 0, I would then create a table row, but I'm not sure how to manually get the next item in the product list, from inside of the jstl foreach loop. When I create a table row, I need to get the next 3 products.

Comment: You are almost done, but what you need is just to iterate over elements and create starting/ending TR tag. I would write pseudocode in answer but I worry people will downvote as incomplete.

Comment: I give it a try, I am just writing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have some problems with my wildfly that does not evaluate expressions. I have to figure it out. For now this is a code that has the concept you are looking for. Do not hesitate to ask.

```
<c:forEach begin="1" end="7" var="element" varStatus="status">
    <c:if test="${status.first}">
        <table>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${status.index % 3 == 0}">
        <tr>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${status.index % 3 == 2 or status.last}">
        </tr>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${status.last}">
        </table>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```